# Do all GUI frameworks use Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, api, user-interface

Microsoft provides Windows API to draw GUI on windows. Do all gui frameworks like Qt, Tk, wxWidgets, GTK, WTL, AWT, Cocoa and Swing etc. use Windows API to draw GUI on windows? We use gui frameworks methods to create gui and on backend they also uses Windows API to draw GUI on windows?

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, any UI framework must use the OS's native UI APIs under the hood, and that is the Win32 API and GDI/GDI+ on Windows, yes.

Comment: if that is the case, how Qt can provide you lots of nice controls that do not exist in standard windows controls?

Comment: @Gupta you get a generic canvas and start drawing. Wire in a the code to handle the non-graphical bells and whistles that the component does and you've got a custom component.

Comment: That is an important point. A GUI framework need not use the windows common controls. It may implement its own control on a canvas.

Comment: @Gupta, the application's top-level window will have to be a Windows "window" object with a window procedure that handles window messages in order to interact with the desktop and window manager. Internally it can reinvent the wheel. It doesn't have to use standard windows controls. But not integrating with the native controls of the OS will make an application stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @user4581301 OK. so these frameworks need to render their own controls and handle the events themselves, right? But at the deepest level it is the OS API.

Comment: @Gupta an interesting design choice in Qt is that Qt doesn't use native widgets (neither for Windows nor any other OS), preferring to draw its own widgets instead.  That is Qt contains code that mimics the look-and-feel of native widgets under various OS's, rather than actually instantiating any native widgets.  It does this because (according to Qt devs) it's easier to get consistent API behavior across many OS's this way.

Comment: @Gupta yes. eryksun's comment laid it out a lot better than I did.

Answer (score 2):

The controls you see as "Win32" are just predefined classes in Windows. For example, a "button" class handles WM_PAINT, WM_ERASEBKGND, WM_LBUTTONDOWN etc to provide the functions you expect (say, the WM_COMMAND when a button is clicked, is posted from the button when it detects a WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP in it's client area).

For custom controls, not found in plain Win32, QT (and other libraries) provide their own ready-to-use classes with custom messages. Eventually everything reduces to plain WM_PAINT for painting, only that in predefined classes the painting is also predefined.

In theory, a 3rd party library might even write directly to the video card with a driver - in reality however everyone uses the normal drawing API - that is, Direct2D, GDI+ and GDI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They all use the Windows API eventually (When run under Windows of course). The Win32 API is the API that can do anything Windows is capable of. The API defines the platform for a developer.